# How to remove php bad tag

Tags: php, tags

How do I remove the `<range/>` and `<heading/>` with "`echo`"?
it seems like this two tags are broken.

```
<LookAt>
   <longitude>121.5445472</longitude>
   <latitude>25.16207778</latitude>
   <altitude>0</altitude>
   <range/>
   <tilt>0</tilt>
   <heading/>
   <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
```

Comment: `<range/>` is a self-closing tag, it's not broken!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like PHP to me, but this is your code with the tags removed:

```
<LookAt>
<longitude>121.5445472</longitude>
<latitude>25.16207778</latitude>
<altitude>0</altitude>
<tilt>0</tilt>
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
```

But if you're trying to embed this as part of a php script, you might want to try something like this....

```
<?php
// insert PHP code here
?>
<LookAt>
<longitude>121.5445472</longitude>
<latitude>25.16207778</latitude>
<altitude>0</altitude>
<tilt>0</tilt>
<altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
</LookAt>
<?php
// insert PHP code here
?>
```